# How to remove a nested JSON element?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

My JSON looks like this.

```
var data =  [{
        "ID"                  : 3,
        "discRec"             : "Some sample record",
        "Tasks"               : [{
                                "ID"          : 7,
                                "discParcel"  : ["string1", "string2"]
                                }]
        }, 
        {
        "ID"                  : 4,
        "discRec"             : "Some sample record 2",
        "Tasks"               : [{
                                "ID"          : 8,
                                "discParcel"  : ["string3", "string4"]
                                }]
        }];
```

Now, i want to remove a first element of 'discParcel' which has ID attr as '8' which has parent ID attr as '4. How to do that in angular 2. Can anybody help.

Comment: that's not a valid syntax in JS or JSON... Is data an array ?

Comment: How is this related to angular2? It's a javascript question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data
    .find(record => record.ID === 4)
    .Tasks.find(task => task.ID === 8)
    .discParcel.shift();
```

Comment: Don't now why I keep forgetting how great `find()` is.

Comment: You are welcome. This solution assumes that there **is** a record with the ID 4 and that it **has** a task with the ID 8. If you cannot guarantee that this is the case, you would have to assign to temporary variables and check for `undefined` between the three operations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is a valid JSON you do it like you would in plain javascript :

```
let arr = JSON.parse(data);
arr.forEach(e => {
  if(e.ID  === 4){
    Tasks.forEach(el => {
      if(el === 8){
        discParcel.shift();
      }
    })  
  }
})
```

Comment: i want to remove a first element of 'discParcel' which has ID attr as '8' which has parent ID attr as '4. How to do that in angular 2. Can you please help

Comment: I tried this data[].ID['3'].Tasks[].ID['8'].discParcel[0]. But it throws an error.